# create calendar by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create, `tr`, `td` through `javascript`, and make a simple calendar from day 1 to day 30.
I created an example with `console.log()` for trying to understand for myself.

When I tried to switch from `console.log()` to `document.getlementById("calendar")` for printing on `html`, it did not print. 
The **error** showed that

> calendar.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in
>   assignment

my understanding with `console.log()`:

```html
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  //open tr tag
  console.log("<tr>");

  for(var i = 1; i <= 30; i++){
    var days = "<td>" + i + "</td>";
    //print 1 to 31 with td tag
    console.log(days);

    //if i divide by 7 and remainder is 0
    if(i % 7 == 0 || i == 31){
      console.log("</tr>");
      console.log("<tr>");
    }
  };
  console.log("</tr>");
};
```

Actual my code with `document.getElementById("calendar")`

```html
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  //open tr tag
  document.getElementById("calendar") += "<tr>";
  for(var i = 1; i <= 30; i++){
    var days = "<td>" + i + "</td>";
    //print 1 to 31 with td tag
    document.getElementById("calendar") += days;
    //if i divide by 7 and remainder is 0
    if(i % 7 == 0 || i == 31){
      document.getElementById("calendar") += "</tr>";
      document.getElementById("calendar") += "<tr>";
    }
  };
  document.getElementById("calendar") += "</tr>";
};
```

my `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>S</th>
                <th>M</th>
                <th>T</th>
                <th>W</th>
                <th>T</th>
                <th>F</th>
                <th>S</th>
            </tr>
            <span id="calendar">

            </span>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="js/calendar.js" ></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

The **error** showed that

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: You have to add it to `document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML` not `document.getElementById("calendar")`.

Comment: you need to build up a string, then set the whole table at once to that string.

Comment: That's right, you cannot add a string like `<tr>` to the result of getElementById(), because this result is not a string, but an element

Comment: you also can't have a span like this inside your table. At this place you can only have a `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't have a `<span>` inside your table where you placed it. A table can only hav a `<tr>` at this place. But you don't need this span at all, you can just append the string direcly to the table, so I moved the ID to the `<table>`-tag.

I also used a variable to build all the HTML and after it's all built I inserted it with [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) at the end of the table.

```js
var table = document.getElementById("calendar");
var htmlstring = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  //open tr tag
  htmlstring += "<tr>";
  for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    var days = "<td>" + i + "</td>";
    //print 1 to 31 with td tag
    htmlstring += days;
    //if i divide by 7 and remainder is 0
    if (i % 7 == 0 || i == 31) {
      htmlstring += "</tr>";
      htmlstring += "<tr>";
    }
  };
  htmlstring += "</tr>";
};
//console.log(htmlstring);
table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlstring)
```

```html
<div>
  <table id="calendar">
    <tr>
      <th>S</th>
      <th>M</th>
      <th>T</th>
      <th>W</th>
      <th>T</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>S</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for giving me useful method!